# Including a 3rd party library from CDN in polymer

Tags: html, polymer

I want to use a 'heavy' 3rd party library from my own custom elements.  This library is 1.2MB and loads other subsequent javascript files when you include it in the page.

I've tried simply including it from my component like so:

```
<link rel="import" href="esri-jsapi.html">
```

Where that html file simply contains

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/esri/css/esri.css">
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/"></script>
```

When I import that file it causes my entire browser (FF 53) to lock up.  If I remove those two lines from esri-jsapi.html (leaving it empty) and paste it into the index.html (bypassing polymer) the page loads fine.

Any idea what's going on there?  Is loading 3rd party scripts from custom elements not allowed?

Comment: Just tried it and runs fine on my machine, have you some special extra setup?

Comment: check this out, maybe you didn't enable the flag? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports . with html imports you should be able to load scripts from the imported file. are you using the polymer cli? it should give you a working setup for your components

Comment: in the index.html I am loading webcomponents-loader, so I shouldn't need to enable that flag on FireFox.  Also, I have used <link rel="import"> on a couple other elements and they load correctly in FireFox.  I think you're right about FireFox being the problem though - I tested this on a chromium based browser and it worked just fine.  Reading more on Polymer it looks like it is made to run on Chrome, and not other browsers - I'm just barking up the wrong tree.  Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Also, I am using the polymer cli and am basing this off the generated "polymer-2-application' template.

Comment: Ok when others of your components run well in firefox, this one should work as well. but i can't investigate further without more code. Polymer is made by google so of course they work on chrome, but this shouldn't be a problem with the polyfills.

Comment: If you have firefox installed can you try this out?  https://github.com/jimmyjamesp/jsapitest   You'll need to do a `bower install` and then `polymer serve --open`   The behavior I get is it works in chromium browsers (I see Hello jsapitest-app! ) but in firefox it hangs until I kill the javascript execution.

Comment: I will try today evening. (Utc + 2)

Comment: Ok tryed it, i misunderstood how you're importing the stuff. doesn't work here either. but.. i tryed the same with polymer 1 and works as expected. didn't find the problem yet, but here is the working repo with polymer 1, maybe you will see a difference. i didn't yet. https://github.com/Mindcraft1/jsapitest-polymer-1

Comment: I've read today, that the polyfills for polymer 2 and custom elements v1 are partly still work in progress. So maybe this issue will be solved with the final polymer 2.0 release

Comment: Hey man, I think you're right.  Thanks for all the help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like polymer 2.0 doesn't support non-chromium browsers when they import large/complicated 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It may be blocked due to the request being cross-origin.  Try refactoring to importing HTML document into the web component.

Comment: Hey, I tried loading other files cross-origin - I loaded jQuery on a different CDN and it loaded.  jQuery is also relatively large so I don't think it's the size alone that is causing the problem.  It might be because the library I'm loading makes subsequent requests to load additional files.